# ASP.NET Identity: Allow only alphanumeric usernames implementation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.net Identity 1.0 and wish to use email addresses for 'username'.

After researching I found this post which appears to suggest a solution: [AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames - how to set it? (RC to RTM breaking change) ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459591/allowonlyalphanumericusernames-how-to-set-it-rc-to-rtm-breaking-change-asp)

I therefore implemented the code (I'm using vb.net):

```
Public Class AccountController
Inherits Controller

Public Sub New()
    Me.New(New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext())))
End Sub

Public Sub New(manager As UserManager(Of ApplicationUser))
    UserManager = manager
    UserManager.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of ApplicationUser)(UserManager) With {.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = False}
End Sub

Public Property UserManager As UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)
```

However when my code calls upon usermanager:

```
 Dim result = Await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, acct.password)
```

I get an exception outside the debugger:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation
>   failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property
>   for more details.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Dim result = Await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, acct.password) Line 294:
>   If result.Succeeded Then Trace.WriteLine("Succeeded creating: " + acct.username)
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more
>   entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) +219
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) +66
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) +60
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync() +63
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.d__0.MoveNext()
>   etc

Seeing as the exception is not caught by the debugger I'm not able to see what 'EntityValidationErrors' is.  However, before I inserted my uservalidator I was able to catch the standard 'non-alphanumeric not allowed' exception.

Anyone any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error happends while entity framework is saving entities to the database. You should read [Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert)

BTW you want to use an email address as a username, so use a correct `UserValidator`

```
Public Class EmailUserValidator(Of TUser As IUser)
    Implements IIdentityValidator(Of TUser)

    Public Function ValidateAsync(user As TUser) As Task(Of IdentityResult) Implements IIdentityValidator(Of TUser).ValidateAsync
        Try
            Dim address = New MailAddress(user.UserName)
            Return Task.FromResult(New IdentityResult())
        Catch
            Return Task.FromResult(New IdentityResult("Invalid Email."))
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Ah yes I see - I had an 'empty' required field.  And thank you for the email validator - that seems to work.  This is an answer thank you.  But I'm still baffled why this exception (or in fact any exception in my Async Function) does not return me to the debugger where I can examine the objects but simply writes the exception to the browser...